# Capitalizing Names before creation. Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get my user model to capitalize all names when a user signs up. It doesn't appear to the working however. I am using devise.

There is a name field in the database.

user model:

```
before_create :capitalize_name    

def capitalize_name
  name_array = name.split(" ")
  name_array.each { |name| name.capitalize! }
  name = name_array.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the result to the local variable `name`. Use `self.name`.

```
self.name = name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
self.name = name_array.join(" ")
```